# How to preview actual poster size?

Tags: texmaker, mac, a0poster

I am going to make an academic poster using latex. I use Texmaker to generation of pdf and Preview (mac) for viewing the pdf.
The document class is `\documentclass[a0, landscape, 20pt]`.

In the pdf document, I see the figures in poster being very small, and thus the details of the figures are almost invisible. I know they will become visible after printing in a0, but I also hope to know if they are in the right size after printing out in a0. How to preview the actual figure size (e.g. from the computer screen or printing in a4 paper) without printing the actual-size poster out?

Thank you very much.

Comment: In Preview, Command-0 should display the document actual size, and then you can navigate around it to see what things look like.  I have no idea if TeXmaker itself allows this. When I am proofreading posters, I usually print them on 11x17inch paper (A3) since my printer can print that size.

Comment: If you are using the Acrobat Viewer then just set the zoom at 100%.